# (IONIC) MomentJS locale not working after build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I'm usign IONIC Framework and using Moment.js for dates. 
When i'm setting all string in french using:

```
moment.locale('fr');
```

It works well on "serve" mode of ionic. But when i build the app for Android or Ios, all dates are en English.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i just included

```
moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js
```

in place of

```
moment/moment.js
moment/locale/fr.js
```